# Getting Values From a Method In A Form Into Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

i have problem with using a method of a form in another form

**EDITED:**

i coded like this:
(i entered 123 in textbox1)

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private string user_code;

  public string UserCode
    {
        get { return user_code; }
    }

    public bool LoginUser()
    {
   user_code = null;


    if(textBox1.Text=="123"){
          user_code="usercode";
             }
         * 
         */
    }
}
```

and usage in form2:

```
          Form1 form1 = new Form1();
          form1.LoginUser();

        MessageBox.Show(form1.UserName);
```

now output is an empty string,i checked with breakpoint and i saw that when i call loginuser in form2 the value in textbox1 become empty and if condition become false
what do you think about problem??

Comment: Your code won't compile. But if you corrected all the errors, it should work correctly. Could you post the code that actually isn't working for you? (But not some overcomplicated code that's not relevant to the question.)

Comment: My answer below still holds true with your edit.  You have a check in the method you are calling from form2 for a textbox.  When you call from another location, that textbox will be initialized with its default value.  If that default is blank (which is normal) then you will never get beyond this check.  You must set that textbox before calling the method if that textbox compare needs to be in the method call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem with [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/278345/Need-data-back-in-form1-Textbox1-while-coming-back#answer2):

> Solution 1 is for ASP.NET, and as I understand it, this is a Windows
>   Form App. So in that case, the easiest way to do this is to just pass
>   a reference from form 1 to form 2 like so:
>
> Form 1:
>
> ```
> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     Form2 a = new Form2(this);
>     a.Show();
>     this.Hide();
> }
> ```
>
> Form 2:
>
> ```
> public partial class Form2 : Form
> {
>     Form1 mainForm;
>
>     public Form2(Form1 mainForm)
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>
>         this.mainForm = mainForm;
>     }
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         mainForm.Show();
>         this.Hide();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> One more thing in form 2 when calling `this.Hide()`:
>
> The form will still exist in memory it will only be hidden from the
>   user. If this is what you intended, then that is fine. However, if you
>   want to dispose of the form 2, call `this.Close()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesnot compile

When you execute functions with out parameters you must mark this parameters as **out**.

```
objfrm1.loginuser(out U, out v, out w, out a,out b, out c);
```

But it will be better use public properties instead out parameters

For example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string user_pass;
        private string user_name;
        private bool insert_ability;
        private bool update_ability;
        private bool delete_ability;

        public string UserPass
        {
            get { return user_pass; }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return user_name; }
        }

        public bool InsertAbility
        {
            get { return insert_ability; }
        }

        public bool UpdateAbility
        {
            get { return update_ability; }            
        }

        public bool DeleteAbility
        {
            get { return delete_ability; }           
        }

        public bool LoginUser()
        {
            /*
              Your code here
              user_pass = "userpass";
              user_name = "username";
              insert_ability = true;

              update_ability = false;
              delete_ability = false;
             * 
             */
        }
    }
```

and usage:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.LoginUser();

            MessageBox.Show(form1.UserName);
```

P.S. And please never use variable name like u, v, w, a, b, c, etc. It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I assume form 1 calls that method when someone enters a username and password into textboxes on the form.  Without knowing more about the data reader or textboxes you use, it looks to me like the call would fail at the first textbox check returning the empty string.  Have you tried setting the textboxes, or better yet binding them to properties that you can set from form 2 before calling the methid in form 1?

EDIT: Added Code based on your update to show what I mean. I have marked the changes to your code.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private string user_code;

  public string UserCode
    {
        get { return user_code; }
    }

    private string _testData;                //THIS IS NEEDED
    public string TestData                   //THIS IS NEEDED
    {
        set { _testData = value;}        //THIS IS NEEDED
    }

    public bool LoginUser()
    {
        user_code = null;
        if(textBox1.Text=="123" || TestData=="123")   //THIS IS NEEDED
        {
            user_code="usercode";
        }
    }
}
```

and usage in form2:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.TestData = "123";  //THIS IS NEEDED
form1.LoginUser();

MessageBox.Show(form1.UserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

After editing your code, it does not compile again.
Are you sure you posted your real code?

The problem is in the line:

> ```
> if(textBox1.Text==123)
> ```

`TextBox.Text` is a `string` property, `123` is `int`.

You cannot directly compare `string` and `int` values.

So what do you want to do?

Do you want open the `Form1` from `Form2`, type username and password on textboxes in `Form1` and pass it into `Form2`, Right?

**EDIT:**
Your solution

```
class FormLogin : Form
    {
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return textBoxUserName.Text; }
            set { textBoxUserName.Text = value; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return textBoxPassword.Text; }
            set { textBoxPassword.Text = value; }
        }

        public FormLogin()
        {
            this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(FormLogin_Closing);
        }

        void FormLogin_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) return;

            if (!LoginUser(UserName, Password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }

        bool LoginUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            // check login and password in database for example

            return true;
        }
    }

    class Form3 :Form
    {
        void LoginButtonClick()
        {
            FormLogin formLogin = new FormLogin();
            formLogin.UserName = "LastUserName";
            //uncomment if you want hide main form
            //this.Hide(); 
            if (formLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Congratulation! You are logged as {0}", formLogin.UserName));
            }

            //this.Show();
        }
    }
```

Don't forget add two buttons on `FormLogin`: **OK** with `DialogResult` property *OK* and **Cancel** with `DialogResult` *Cancel*.

Comment: yes,i found the answer,see my answer above,do u have better way??thanks